# Swift - Inheriting protocol does not inherit generic where constraint

Tags: swift, casting, extension-methods, exc-bad-access, swift-protocols

I am trying to migrate to using protocols instead of subclassing, but I still would like to be able to delegate up to the "super" implementation of a certain method before performing more specific logic. Below is the code I've written to demonstrate the functionality I want, but it's crashing. If this is for some reason a bad approach/missing the point of protocol oriented programming then I would love to learn why, but also right now I just need to know why this is crashing. Thanks!

```
import UIKit

protocol A where Self: UIView { }
extension A {
  func method () {
    print("protocol A")
  }
}

protocol B: A { }
extension B {
  func method () {
    print("protocol B")
    (self as A).method()
  }
}

class X: UIView, B {
  func method () {
    print("class X")
    (self as B).method()
  }
}
```

This code is invoked simply by doing this:

```
let x = X()
x.method()
```

The code above crashes with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS at this line:

```
(self as A).method()
```

Comment: Please post code as text, not as a picture. Pictures can't be searched or referenced and they are harder to read.

Comment: Possible the same as https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-6645 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a partial answer, even though I still do not understand exactly what is going. I noticed that this crash was only occurring when I had the

```
where Self: UIView
```

constraint on protocol A. If I remove the constraint, no crash occurs. This made me think that somehow the object is losing its status as a UIView somewhere along the way, and that this is the problem. More specifically, it seems that when protocol B inherits from protocol A, it does not inherit the

```
where Self: UIView
```

clause, meaning that casting to B does not imply that the resulting entity is a UIView. Following this line of thinking, I was able to make the above code work by changing:

```
(self as B).method()
```

to

```
(self as B & UIView).method()
```

This seems like a bug to me, so I'm going to try to bring it to the attention of the Swift team.

Comment: Yes but isn't that what my link already says? In other words, isn't this the bug they already know about?